# elasticsearch query to find documents that don't exist

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way in Elasticsearch through filters, queries, aggregations etc to search for a list of document ids and have returned which ids did not hit?

With a small list it is easy enough to compare the results against the requested ids list but I'm dealing with lists of ids in the tens of thousands and it is not going to be performant to do that.

Comment: What interface/language are you using? Might help with answering your question

Comment: Directly? Or using Java, PHP, Perl? This comment was mainly for more specific code (be it in the one I use)

Comment: We are using Java, but not the java client lib. Making REST calls from java code.

Comment: how did you end up doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-not-filter.html

```
"filtered" : {
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "name.first" : "shay" }
    },
    "filter" : {
        "not" : {
            "range" : {
                "postDate" : {
                    "from" : "2010-03-01",
                    "to" : "2010-04-01"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Take a look at the guide at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html

Comment: I don't think using a not filter would work since it filters out matched documents. In the case I'm looking at there are no match documents. To clarify, take an index with docs 1,2,3,4,5,6,7. User does a search and gets 1,4,7 as the result. The user than saves this list and comes back the next day after another user has deleted doc with id 4. User 1 now does an ids search for docs with ids 1,4,or,7 and gets back only 2 hits. I need a query that will tell them that 4 did not hit a document. While trivial in this example, it's not so trivial when dealing with an ID list thousands long

Comment: Ok, that part was unclear (for me). Then I would suggest using an search on each _uid, and do as you proposed. I think a BulkRequest instead of Search, because it will return the requested queries in the same order as queried. If, however, the number of document is too large, use SearchScroll (like I suggested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918412/elasticsearch-multiple-scrolls-java-api ). I'm using this for millions of items. (be it as a backup plan)

Comment: Maybe Groovy script can help https://www.elastic.co/blog/running-groovy-scripts-without-dynamic-scripting . I'm not sure how it work, but I think you can send it as a PostFilter/script. So invert filter the ids gathered from result